# cross compile issue with simple hello program

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

Background : Trying to setup a cross compiler environment for arm target (TQ2440/Mini2440)

On HOST running Red Hat:

1. Wrote a simple hello program
2. `gcc -o hello hello.c`
3. compiles successfully
4. `./hello`
5. displays the hello world message
6. `rm hello`
7. `arm-linux-gcc -o hello hello.c`
8. `file hello`
9. It says `32bit compiled for ARM compatible for Linux 2.0.0`

Transfer the "hello" binary file to TARGET

1. `chmod a+x hello`
2. `./hello`
3. The problem:

   ```
   /bin/sh: ./hello: not found
   ```

Can anyone point out my mistake or what am I missing here?

---

I executed ldd on host: `ldd hello` and I got:

```
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/bin/ldd: line 1:  
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2: cannot execute binary file 
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/bin/ldd: line 1: 
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2: cannot execute binary file 
ldd: /usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2 exited with unknown exit code (126)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I was transfering the file through ftp. You need to enter **bin** to switch to binary transfer mode. Works fine now.

Comment: Accept your own answer when it's old enough that you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `ldd hello` and see if it complains about any missing dynamic libraries.

Comment: Thanx for reply Graham.I executed ldd on host:

ldd hello ---- and I got
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/bin/ldd: line 1: /usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2: cannot execute binary file
/usr/local/arm/3.3.2/bin/ldd: line 1: /usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2: cannot execute binary file
ldd: /usr/local/arm/3.3.2/lib/ld-linux.so.2 exited with unknown exit code (126)